# Handlebars.Net with local File path

Tags: c#, handlebars.net

I have a configuration value that represents a folder where some files are available for download.  This value is a handlebars template:

```
"D:\{{identifier1}}\{{identifier2}}\SomeFolder\{{version}}"
```

This value is set per environment by our deploy server.

The problem is that when I run the template through like this:

```
var template = Handlebars.Compile(_configuration.FilePathFormat);

        return template(new
        {
            identifier1 = 123,
            identifier2 = 456,
            version = "latest"
        });
```

The result I get back is this:

```
R:{{identifier1}}{{identifier2}}\SomeFolder{{version}}
```

What I expect:

```
R:\123\456\SomeFolder\latest
```

For some reason it is escaping the handlebars and I don't want that.  I have been unable to find anything on disabling escape characters, and no amount of slashes has worked to render the template correctly.

Also, if I put a space between the slash and the handlebar placeholder, it compiles and renders correctly, but then it has a space in the file path.

I found a [site that let me test handlebars.js](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/), but it behaves differently than handlebars.net

Comment: This was a bug in Handlebars.Net that is now fixed.

Comment: Thank you Rex!  I'll pull the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Fixed in Handlebars.net**

Sice version 1.9.3, released right after I reported the bug, this now works just fine. You have to double your slashes in the template to escape them for Handlebars.Net, same as for Handlebars.js,

```
var templateText = @"D:\\{{identifier1}}\\{{identifier2}}\\SomeFolder\\{{version}}";
var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.Compile(templateText);

var path = compiledTemplate(new
{
    identifier1 = 123,
    identifier2 = 456,
    version = "latest"
});
```

**Original answer:**
Yes, it seems Handlebars.net has some weird handling of escape characters.

The simplest workaround is to just invert the slashes in the template string.

```
var templateText = @"D:/{{identifier1}}/{{identifier2}}/SomeFolder/{{version}}";
var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.Compile(templateText);

var pathWithInvertedSlashes = compiledTemplate(new
{
    identifier1 = 123,
    identifier2 = 456,
    version = "latest"
});
// Inverted slashes normally work fine on Windows, but if you want to
// 'fix' them you can always do
var canonicalPath = Path.GetFullPath(pathWithInvertedSlashes);
```

Comment: I started down this path (forcing the \ to /), but was hoping I was missing something.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Handlebars.net has a fixed lookahead when it encounters a backslash. I reported a bug at https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net/issues/247

Comment: This bug has been fixed in the latest version of Handlebars.Net. Thanks for raising it!